# oracle query to check for rows with same ID and a given field are all the same

Tags: sql, oracle

So I need a query that will run in Oracle that gives me all the ID's for rows in which a given field has the same value on every row with that ID and there are no rows with that ID that have a non-matching value in that given field.

So if I have a table like this, and I'm looking for the value X in FieldB:

```
ID     FieldA     FieldB     FieldC
1      A          X          D
2      B          X          E
2      C          Y          F
1      D          X          G
3      E          X          H
3      F          Z          I
1      G          X          J
1      H          X          K
1      I          X          L
```

I want something that will give me ID 1 only, because every row for that ID has X in FieldB and there are no rows for ID 1 that don't have X in FieldB. I tried the below query:

```
SELECT 
        a.ID
    from 
        tablename a
    where
        exists (select 1 from tablename where ID = a.ID and FieldB = 'X')
        and not exists (select 1 from tablename where ID = a.ID and (FieldB != 'X' or FieldB is null))
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_TS2
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
```

which I assume means my query is terribly inefficient (or just plain wrong). I imagine there's an easy way to do this, but I haven't found one. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(fieldB) = max(fieldB) and -- all the same
       min(fieldB) = 'X';
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work for me because the "FieldB" is non-numeric.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity . . . And what does that have to do with anything?  Why would a string or a date/time not work?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a little more understandable, use a having clause but just find the ones where the distinct count of your column is only equal to 1:

```
select a.ID
from tablename a
where a.FieldB = 'X'
group by a.ID
having count(distinct FieldB) = 1;
```

Comment: It is pure luck that it returns correct result *in this case*. If ID = 3 contained, for example, Z in fieldB for both of its rows, your query would return IDs 1 and 3, while only ID = 1 satisfies condition that it should have X in fieldB.

Comment: This still returns rows where FieldB is null, not X.